# Joomla - Load database results one by one in a MODULE

Tags: jquery, joomla, module, pagination

I have created a custom module that returns the matched results of users from a third party component using a query. The module as such works fine and loads the results as expected. However, I am unable to limit the results shown per page. There are more than 100 results in some cases so I want to either

1. Show pagination and limit results per page to 5)  OR
2. Use jQuery type slider to show one result at a time with next and previous arrows
3. Use a Load MORE button at the bottom of 5 results to show next 5 results and so on.

I am open to any of these whichever is easy / easiest.

I do not have a custom component otherwise I could have used Joomla's Jpagination I think but the issue is there is nothing in the URL that can be used to limit per page results because this is only a module.

This is what the helper.php looks like

```
// Obtain a database connection
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

// Query database to find matches for the logged 
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
            ->select($db->quoteName(array('a.user_id','a.field_52','a.field_16','b.filename')))
            ->from($db->quoteName('#__thirdpartycomponent_profiles','a'))
            ->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__thirdpartycomponent_photos', 'b').' ON (' . $db->quoteName('a.main_photo'). ' = ' . $db->quoteName('b.id') . ')')
            ->where('field_16!='.$table->field_16);

// Prepare the query
$db->setQuery($query);

// Load the row.
$matches = $db->loadObjectList();
```

And this is what the module's default.php looks like

```
.....
foreach ( $matches as $matches) {

?>

<div style="margin-bottom: 8px; margin-top: 12px;"> <b><?php echo  "Rating".$matches->field_52;?></b>
.....
```

Please note that the above foreach logic returns all results at once. I am looking to limit it to reduce server load and not show 100s of results. My query is much refined than what I posted above (to make it easy to read) so yes, it displays only very relevant results also I am planning to limit the results to 50. I still do not want to load 50 results all at once.

Like all of you smart programmers out there, I am a big fan of light weight coding, less requests and queries. Any help to achieve this will be appreciated. Thank you so much for your time. !

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Joomla 3.x, you can use the following to limit your query:

```
$query->setLimit(5);
```

Of course you can change the value `5` to whatever you wish. If you're using anything older than Joomla 3.x, then you can use the following:

```
$db->setQuery($query,0,5);
```

In this instance, the first parameter (`0`) is the start and the second (`5`) is the limit.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, that answer helps in fetching results by limiting which needs multiple queries. Even if multiple queries is the only option, how do I implement the limits in the form of a pagination or next /previous loader? In other words, how to loop the query based on the current results range.  I use Joomla 3.x.

Comment: I think you're thinking of Ajax. Do you mean you want the first (for example) 5 results to be queried, then then when a user click *next* on the pagination, it loads the next 5 results?